# When does Schwarz inequality become an equality?

Tags: inequality

In Spivak Calculus you are asked to prove that in Schwarz inequality, equality holds only when $y_1 = y_2 = 0$ or when there is a number $\lambda$ such that $x_1 = \lambda y_1$ and $x_2 = \lambda y_2$.

I can go from $x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} + \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$ to $x_1y_2 = x_2y_1$ but then I got stuck, or is it that the implication is the other way around?

Comment: That's correct. Conclude that if neither of $y_1, y_2$ are 0, then $\frac {x_1}{y_1} = \frac {x_2}{y_2}$, and set it to be your favorite parameter. Then deal with the case $y_1 y_2 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you Calvin, with your $\lambda = \frac{x_1}{y_1}$ trick I was able to complete the proof.

Comment: $x_1,\,x_2,\,y_1,\,y_2,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @scjorge Yep, all real numbers.

Comment: For the Schwarz Inequality, $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} + \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$ in the question should be $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}  \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$

Answer (score 21):

$|\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle|=\|\mathbf{x}\|\,\|\mathbf{y}\| \iff  \mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are *linearly dependent*, i.e. if $\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{y}$ (or, trivially, if either $\mathbf{x}$ or $\mathbf{y}$ is zero; handle this first to get it out of the way).

($\implies$): Follow the normal Schwarz inequality argument, but equality will force $\mathbf{x}={\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle\over \langle\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\rangle}\mathbf{y}$

($\Longleftarrow$): Substitute $\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{y}$.

Comment: How do you find =⟨,⟩/⟨,⟩*? (i.e. which inequality argument did you follow to get that) Is it the same as x=||x||/||y||*y?

Comment: It's all right but to be precise, the equation that you put is in fact $x= \frac{\langle y,x\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle} y$, the order of the braket is inverse

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\right)\left(y_1^2+y_2^2\right)-(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2=(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2
$$
we get equality if and only if $x_1y_2=x_2y_1$.